# How to select a row of matrix with needed condition

Tags: matrix

I'd like to select row of matrix which Dimension=3:

```
MT={{1,2,5,2},{2,4,4},{3,2},{5,5,2},{1,2},{3,1,4},{4,4,1,2}}
```

I need the new output is:

```
out={{2,4,4},{5,5,2},{3,1,4}}
```

But I use the Select function but out but is:

```
In[15]:= Select[MT, Dimensions[#] == 3 &]

Out[15]= {}
```

Does any more appropriate methods to select Dimension=3 rows?
Please help me to solve this problem, thanks.

Comment: `Select[MT, Dimensions[#] == {3} &]` or much better `Select[MT, Length[#] == 3 &]` ... As a side note: avoid variable names starting with capital letter.

Comment: What @BlacKow said.  Plus, reserve the term "matrix" for rectangular arrays.  (Ideally, those that pass the `MatrixQ` test.)

Answer (score 1):

A number of ways:

```
lst = {{1, 2, 5, 2}, {2, 4, 4}, {3, 2}, {5, 5, 2}, {1, 2}, {3, 1, 
    4}, {4, 4, 1, 2}};
Select[lst, Length@# == 3 &]
Pick[lst, Length /@ lst, 3]
Cases[lst, {_, _, _}]
3 /. GroupBy[lst, Length]
```